# Algebraic vs Geometric Picard groups

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, line-bundles

Given a smooth manifold $P$. I found two definition of a Picard group. The first one is algebraic, $Pic(C^{\infty}(P))$ is defined as the set of self-equivalence bimodules (Morita equivalence) with tensor product of bimodules as group operation. The second one is geometric, $Pic(P)$ is defined as the set of isomorphism classes of line bundles over $P$ with tensor product of vector bundles as group operation. I know there is some relation between the two concepts via Serre-Swan Theorem. Yet I don't know what is the exact relation, I mean, are they isomorphic? Can one of them be seen as a (normal) subgroup of the other? I would like an answer avoiding use of algebraic geometric terminologies, like affine spaces or schemes, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

They are different. The bimodule definition is for rings, not commutative rings; for commutative rings you should be using invertible modules rather than invertible bimodules, and then the two definitions agree by the Serre-Swan theorem. Invertible modules correspond to finitely generated projective modules of rank $1$, which are in turn identified with line bundles.

Answer (score 0):

For commutative algebras, the "bimodule" Picard group is isomorphic to the semidirect product of the automorphism group of the algebra and the subgroup of (isoclasses of) symmetric bimodules.

The symmetric bimodules in Pic (via Serre-Swan) identifies with line bundles.

The automorphism group of the algebra maps into Pic via $u\mapsto Au$ where $Au$ is the bimodule equal to $A$ as left module but with right action twisted by $u$.